# Google Map issue with XHTML file

Tags: google-maps

I am facing a weird issue with Google Map API V3. I had a previous version of the code, which I migrated to new version V3. The extension is XHTML since this particular file is used as a control in other application. I have created a sample code, which when I execute as stand alone runs fine and displays the google map, but when the similar file is called through another application it is causing an issue where map is loaded but is invisible. Just for information i am using this file from Informatica IDD application. Below is a snippet. Looking for any kind of lead.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?&amp;3.21&amp;key=AIzaSyBO11CFgFCL8GnV3-tWZyQOmA8mbO9MP8E&amp;sensor=false"
     type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* CONSTANTS */
   var geocoder = null;
   var map = null;
   /* INITIALIZATION */
   function initialize() {
     alert("initialize");
     geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

     // Draw the map 
     /*var startPoint = parseCoordinate(VALUE_SITE_COORDINATE);
     alert(startPoint);*/
     var startPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(24.886, -70.268);
       var mapProp = {
      center:startPoint,
      zoom:5,
      mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     };
     map =new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapProp);
     alert("after new map");
     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
      google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
      alert("in idle");
     });
     var bimage = "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue-dot.png";

     // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
     //markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: startPoint,
      map: map,
      icon: bimage
     });
     marker.setVisible(true);  // visible_changed triggered
     marker.setMap(map);       
     
   }
  //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:850px;height:850px;"> 
  <!--<div>
   <h:form id="geomap">
    <div class="title-bar">
     <h:outputText value="Geo Fence Maintenance"/>
    </div> 
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;"> 
     
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;">

    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;float:left;">
    
    </div>
    <div style="width:50%;"> 

    </div>
    <div style="width:100%;padding-bottom:10px;">
     <div style="float:left;">
     </div>
     
    </div>
    <div>
     <div id="divCoordinates" style="width:200px;height:200px;float:left;padding-top:5px;padding-left:5px;">
     </div>
     <div>
       <div id="map_canvas" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </h:form>
  </div>-->
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Further Analysis
I think i found the root cause but not the solution. The issue is my google map is being called through JSF. I guess some update in IE11 is breaking the functionality. The similiar problem i have encountered in link below. http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/mapAjax.xhtml It have google map invisible in IE 11 but shows up when it is opened in firefox. I have similiar kind of issue with IE11. Any suggestion how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You have "amp;" in your script src url, but I think that is probably as result of your copy/pasting. Definitely check your src url to make sure you are actually loading the google maps api.

My guess is that your real problem is this line:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

You are not loading the Google API so google.setOnLoadCallack() does not exist when you are calling it.

Add this to your page just before the script tag for the google maps:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

You will need to add your API key if you want it to work for your application when it is deployed to your server.

**Alternatively**, you could put a callback function in the url for the google maps script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thank you  reply Taylor. I have modified the code accordingly. I am using google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize); to call initialize function. Initialize function is getting called. If i run that xhtml page stand alone i can see the map and the blue marker. The issue is when i calling the same page from oh